# Django ORM bulk read query

Tags: python, django

I have a model called `User` which has a property called `is_free()` which runs a query like this

```
@property
def is_free(self):
    return User.objects.free_user().filter(id=self.id).exists()
```

When i try to get multiple users and populate them using a `for` loop there are many SQL queries executed based on the number of users i am populating which is affecting the API timings. For Example -

```
for user in selected_users:
    user_list.append({"id": user.id,
        "name": user.name,
        "is_free": user.is_free,
        "title_display": user.title_display})
```

Is there a better way to do this without changing the model? I am using Django 1.8 and Python 2.7

Tastypie response

```
"user_list": [
    {
        "name": "Nithin",
        "is_free": false,
        "title_display": "Android Developer"
        "id": 1733
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Comment: **`job`** ?  is that a typo?

Comment: Updated it, it was a typo.

Comment: What does the **`.free_user(...)`** method?  and what is **`selected_users`**?

Comment: and how it is related `is_free` and your API response?

Comment: `selected_users` is a query to fetch a list of users based on company, `free_user` is a query which runs another query filtering out the paid users from the free users`, I will update the response. The problem statement is like there are paid companies and each company can have paid users and free users

Comment: You could use the annotations to let the database do the work upon initial query. Check out the doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best best is using annotations

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate

You can do something like:

```
selected_users = User.objects.annotate(is_free_user=Q(*whatever condition you need*)).filter(*whatever your filter is*)
for user in selected_users:
    user_list.append({"id": user.id,
        "name": user.name,
        "is_free": user.is_free_user,
        "title_display": user.title_display})
```

Hope that helps